# How stop the pawn from moving when in play mode in Unreal Engine 5?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, unreal

How to stop the pawn from moving when in play mode in Unreal? I am new to Unreal and the game view should be still like the game view of Unity.

Comment: What exactly is happening?

Comment: @MaxPlay when in game view, i am able to move, but i do not want to move or rotate, the default pawn is enabling movement when in game view, how to make it not happen ?

Comment: @VINNUSAURUS Maybe unpossess pawn? Try F8 in playmode